# How to block other Gesture Recognizers when one is enable

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have silly problem with gesture recognizers. In the Interface Builder I have few of them. Three of it are Pan Gesture Recognizers. One of it is in the different view. I want to block rest when this one is calling.

I will be glad for good answer because right now I have no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might do something like this

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
      if(gestureRecognizer == THE_GESTURE_WHICH_SHOULD_WORK)
          return YES;

   return NO;

}
```

Make sure you set delegate to all your gestures.

It might help you, for more clarification visit the [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/)

Thanks.